# Why is it invalid to reassign a pointer that was previously assigned nullptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, nullptr

I am new to C++ and am following the book "Programming Principles and Practices using C++". I came across something that I could not understand completely. Hopefully someone can help me understand this.

Why is this invalid?

```
int* p = nullptr;
*p = 7;
```

Comment: Where have you allocated space for `p`?

Comment: @StephenNewell `int *p = nullptr;` allocates space for `p`.  Either in automatic or static storage depending where this line was found .

Comment: You're not reassigning `p`.   You're reassigning what `p` points at.   And since `p` is a null pointer, reassigning what it points at gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: I suspect the confusion is that you think you are _reassigning a pointer_.  `*p` means "the int that `p` is pointing to".  Your code is assigning `7` to the int that `p` is pointing to.  It's invalid because `p` is not pointing to an int.

Answer (score 6):

`nullptr` is a special address. In particular, nothing can ever be stored there. Attempting to dereference a null pointer is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a) (in fact, it's the first example on that list).

Now, to be clear, what you're doing is *not* reassigning a pointer itself.  Given this code:

```
int* p = nullptr;
*p = 7;
```

This is *dereferencing* the pointer and then reassigning the *value* of the thing that the pointer is pointing at. And since `nullptr` does not point at anything, dereferencing a `nullptr` is undefined behavior, so the assignment is invalid.

Now, given this code:

```
int q = 42;
int* p = nullptr;
p = &q;
```

*This* is reassigning the pointer itself. This is perfectly valid. We started with a pointer that is pointing to nothing, and then tell it to point to something else (in this case, a local variable). Notice that I don't put a `*` when I assign to `p` in this example. I never dereference a `nullptr`, so I never hit that particular problem.

Comment: Nor is it an address -- it's a keyword, that when assigned to a pointer, causes that pointer to be null

Comment: It's actually a keyword, but using that keyword gives a null pointer constant, which is a value that compares equal to zero.   Before `nullptr` was a language keyword, the equivalent could be achieved by `int *p = 0` (which involved a conversion of an integral value to a pointer type) or (more explicitly) `int *p = (int *)0`.   Assigning a pointer to be equal to a null pointer constant (however it is done) gives a null pointer.   And dereferencing a null pointer gives undefined behaviour.